# Plot a user-defined equation using R base plots

Tags: r, plot

I would like to plot an experimental equation using the base graphics module of R. How can I do it?

The equation is as follows: `Y = 0.000028684X^2.907552726`

Y=0.000028684*X^2.907552726

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `text` function:

```r
plot(function(X) 0.000028684*X^2.907552726, ylab = 'Y', xlab = 'X',
     xlim = c(0, 100))
text(20, 15, quote(Y == paste('0.000028684')*X^2.907552726))
```

[image]